# evaluating a Dirac delta integral

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

I have $L(u,v,s',t')=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}E(s,t,z)\delta(\frac{z}{z_0}s+(1-\frac{z}{z_0})u-Ms', \frac{z}{z_0}t+(1-\frac{z}{z_0})v-Mt')dz$

Where $E(s,t,z)=\delta(s)\delta(t)f(z)$, basically a line in 3D volume

Simplifying the integral knowing s=0 and t=0 I get

$L(u,v,s',t')=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(z)\delta((1-\frac{z}{z_0})u-Ms', (1-\frac{z}{z_0})v-Mt')dz$

So my confusion is I wish to numerically evaluate this integral in python but given the delta(x,y) are a function of z, when I solve for z I get

$z=z_0(\frac{Ms'}{u}-1)=z_0(\frac{Mt'}{v}-1)$
leaving me unsure what to use to simplify like $\int f(x)\delta(x_0)dx=f(x_0) $ would.

Comment: If these two quantities are equal you will get $f(z_0(...))$ otherwise $0$

Comment: So if M and z_0 are constant, you are saying that s'/u = t'/v, meaning the only points I will have data for are essentially L(u,u,s',s')  or L(v,v,t',t')?

Comment: I guess it makes sense, given the line is in the origin

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean under $\delta(a,b)$? Does it mean $\delta(a-b)$?

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): Where are the $ds$ and $dt$ integration measures and integrations?

Comment: I'm only integrating with respect to z. Note that s' and t' are not the same as s and t. Essentially I have a 3D volume (s,t,z) that emits light in the distribution of E(z) which goes through some lenses and lands on a new 2D plane (s',t'). (u,v) represent where the light-ray passes through the main lens.